# Using ADAM to validate users in a DMZ zone

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, adam

ISS and ASP.NET.

In my setup I have a web application that must be accessable from:

1. an organisatition of 3000 users
2. 200 external users

The solution is hosted in the organisations DMZ.

Initially i was hoping to do AD based authentication for the 3000 org users, so that they wouldnt need to remember more passwords.

Now the hosting provider tells me that i cannot access the AD due to security constraints.

What are my options?

Is ADAM a viable approch? I.e. sync from the org AD  to ADAM? Does it work?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want a custom-code solution for this, you're probably looking for something like [AdamSync](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786455.aspx) to get your AD users into ADAM.